# jqGrid within jquery draggable performance issues (IE)

Tags: jqgrid

Having performance issues with a window that is draggable, and has a jqgrid in it. When in IE the dragging is really laggy (other browsers are fine).

What could cause this, and are there any workarounds?

Edit: 
Example: http://jsfiddle.net/cnd5041/4q6ybtw8/1/
Yes, using jquery draggable:

```
$('#container').draggable();
```

Comment: Could you provide the demo which can be used to reproduce the problem? Which version of jqGrid you use? How you make window draggable? Do you use jQuery UI Darggable? Or you use `jqdnr.js` which is part of jqGrid of you use some other way? In which web browser and in which version you have the performance problems?...

Comment: Sorry, thought I had the jQuery UI Draggable in there. I updated with jsfiddle, but IE seems to be struggling with it sometimes so let me know if there's an issue